# How to block a resizable property of sencha textareafield

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to block a resizable property of sencha textareafield?

I tried by using css as

```
.textareaclass {
  resize: 'none'
}
```

and added `textareaclass` to cls of textarea. But it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Odd, I can't resize a textarea in ExtJS 4. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using sencha touch 2.2

Comment: sencha touch is not ExtJS, I fixed your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `cls` property of the textareafield just sets a class on the field element. This is one of divs wrapped around the real textarea dom element.
By using the `inputCls` property, the css class is set on the input/textarea dom element itself.

```
Ext.create('Ext.field.TextArea', {
    label: 'myLabel',
    inputCls: 'textareaclass'
});
```

Also make sure you're not adding single quotation marks around the css property value.

```
.textareaclass {
    resize: none;
}
```